# Rails DB Migration can't add a foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I've got a problem trying to run a migration in my rails project.

I have a simple addition of two tables:

```
class ModifyCurrentTablesToNewDesign < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change

    # Some other migrations...

    # New Table Companies

    create_table :companies do |t|
      t.string :name
    end

    # New Table Teams

    create_table :teams do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.belongs_to :companies, :index => true, :foreign_key => true
    end

    # Some oooother migrations...

  end
end
```

And when a run it, I've got this:

```
-- create_table(:companies)
   -> 0.0036s
-- create_table(:teams)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "company_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "teams" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_e080df8a94"
FOREIGN KEY ("company_id")
  REFERENCES "companies" ("id")
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:762:in `add_foreign_key'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:217:in `block in create_table'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:216:in `each_pair'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:216:in `create_table'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:661:in `block in method_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:631:in `block in say_with_time'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:631:in `say_with_time'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:651:in `method_missing'
/Users/julian/Development/sikuani/plataforma-eventos/db/migrate/20160121164754_modify_current_tables_to_new_design.rb:35:in `change'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:605:in `exec_migration'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `block in migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:587:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1040:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1040:in `ddl_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:993:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `block in migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:951:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:951:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:819:in `up'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:797:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Isn't supposed that when the table `companies` is created, by default a column `id` is created within? Can you see why could this be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have a *1:M* relationship between companies and teams.
You need to use the singular because a team belongs to **a single company**, not multiple companies.

```
t.belongs_to :company, :index => true, :foreign_key => true
```

Comment: It worked! ... but now I'm so confused :/, if the table is called `companies` (plural), the relation isn't between table names?

Comment: Think about it this way, a team belongs to **a single company**, not multiple companies.